# Inserting a javascript var as markup with YUI2 insertAfter()

Tags: javascript, html, yui2

I'm trying to define an element in javascript as a string and then insert it. Have I defined it wrong, or is there another problem?

```
var NEW_ROW= '<TR class="NewRow"></TR>';
YAHOO.util.Dom.insertAfter(NEW_ROW, referenceNode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reversed:

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.insertAfter(referenceNode, NEW_ROW);
```